# Mongoose virtuals definition. Arrow function vs "Traditional" function

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, anonymous-function, arrow-functions

I am following an Express tutorial.

I had an error when trying to access one of my model virtuals.

My model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const authorSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    first_name: {type: String, required: true, maxlength: 100},
    family_name: {type: String, required: true, maxlength: 100}
});

// virtual for author's full name: 
authorSchema.virtual('name').get(
    () => {
        return `${this.first_name} ${this.family_name}`;
    }
);


// Export model:
module.exports = mongoose.model('Author', authorSchema);
```

Request Handler:

```
exports.get_author1 = (req,res, next) => {

    Author.find().then(
        (results) => {
            res.end(results[0].name); 
    // "results" returns a list of objects (each object represent an author in my db) here I am accessing the first author object of the list and using the dot notation to access its 'name' virtual. 
        }
    )
};
```

The generated answer will be: *undefined undefined*

After a couple hours not understanding what I did wrong, I changed my virtual declaration to :

```
authorSchema.virtual('name').get(
    function() {
        return `${this.first_name} ${this.family_name}`;
    }
);
```

Using function(){} instead of () => {}, and it worked now getting the response I wanted: *Patrick Rothfuss*.

My question is then **what is the difference between the traditional anonymous function ( function()
{} ) and arrow function ( ()=>{} )** especially regarding their use when declaring a virtual ?

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions
As said on MDN arrow functions don’t have a binding to `this` like a traditional function.